# Can someone help me ID this components labelling for Li Ion charger

Tags: battery-charging, components

I am trying to fix a charger for a Dewalt 20v Li-Ion power tool set.  I have inspected the board and this little guy seems charred/burnt around the PCB.  I know its a Schottky Diode, [image: stps20150ctDIODE] but I don't know what the GK080, VW, or CHN 514 stands for.  I am just a tinkerer trying to learn electronics and want to make sure I know exactly what value I need or don't need.  Digi-Key Part Number 497-2730-5-ND looks similar but the leg on the one in my picture has extra insulation.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Not this? http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/9a/96/fd/db/b9/f2/41/a1/CD00002411.pdf/files/CD00002411.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002411.pdf

Comment: That digikey part number is right. The leg insulation was put afterwards.

Comment: @Bradman175,  Can you fill me in on what the other numbers/letters mean underneath the top part number?  Does CHN mean made in China? 514=date of manufacture?

Comment: Hard to tell since the datasheet doesn't say. CHN would definitely mean made in china. 514 could be the manufacturing week. VW could be traceability code.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, now that I look closer at the picture, that "insulation" on the left leg, is more like a ferrite bead glued in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2x10A   150V 0.69V common cathode